# Problema de consulta con SQLite en python

Tags: python, sqlite

Tengo un problema que cuando hago una consulta a mi BD con python me manda este error

> OperationalError: unrecognized token: "4BDCompleta"

Mi función es la siguiente:

```
def Conexion():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Device4.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = cur.execute('SELECT ID_Site FROM 4BDCompleta')
```

Todo está bien escrito y Mi BD se llama **Device4** y se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de lo que pueda ser ? Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: no sé que tanto se admite la sintaxis SQL, pero puedes probar con los backtick haciendo \`4BDCompleta\`

Comment: Gracias si era eso @Christian !